# Lowercase \figurename for non-English languages

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, babel, languages, cleveref

In almost all languages, the words corresponding to `\figurename` and `\tablename` are used in the text in lowercase. What is the best practice to achieve this?

For example, while in English the code

```
See \figurename~\ref{fig1} for the method and \tablename~\ref{tab2} for the result.
```

is rendered with uppercase letters for Figure and Table:

```
See Fig. 1 for the method and Table 2 for the result.
```

in Spanish a similar code should be rendered with lowercase letters:

```
Véase fig. 1 para el método y tabla 2 para el resultado.
```

However, in the caption we still need uppercase:

```
\caption{Método}
```

should still be rendered with an uppercase for Fig.:

```
Fig. 1. Método.
```

What is the best practice to achieve this?

I am modifying a class file for a journal, so the solution should be simple and understandable to the users without lengthy and clumsy instructions, ad-hoc commands, or fancy packages.

I considered these solutions:

- To oblige the authors to write `Véase \MakeLowercase\figurename~\ref{fig1} para el método`.
- To define some ad-hoc command, such as `\lowercasefigurename`, and oblige the authors to write `Véase \lowercasefigurename~\ref{fig1} para el método`.
- To oblige the authors to use packages such as `cleveref`.

All this is not practical: people would not do it.

Other options:

- To define `\figurename` as lowercase "fig.", and to redefine all conceivable definitions of `\caption` (and probably `\makeindex` and who knows what else) to use `\MakeUppercase\figurename` instead of `\figurename`. Of course, this is asking for compatibility problems with packages.
- To instruct the authors not to use `\figurename` at all and directly write `Véase fig.~\ref{fig1}`. This is of course bad practice: for example, some journals use "fig.", some "figura", and some "illustración"; some journals use "tabla" and some "cuadro", which is the whole purpose of `\figurename` and `\tablename`.
- To manually rewrite every submitted paper to substitute each `\figurename` with `\MakeLowercase\figurename`. Of course this is labor-consuming and error-prone.
- To leave the problem as is, which would result in horrible and ungrammatical text like "Véase Fig. 1 para el método".

What would be a viable solution? What is a common practice for non-English languages?

Comment: With `cleveref`, you only have to  write `cref{ …} to obtain  figure (or figures if there are several references) and its number, and `\Cref{…}` to obtain  `Figure(s)`.

Comment: I personally can do it, but many authors are not familiar with `cleveref`. My practice shows that most people would just ignore the instructions and do what they are used to do.

Comment: `\zzzname` macros are there to customise generated texts there is no need to use them explicitly. I would just write `Figure~\ref{zz}` and if I wanted it lower case `figure~\ref{zz}`

Comment: I think `\zzzname` is good practice. As author, I always write `see \figurename~\ref{zz}` and, depending on the journal where I send my paper (different journals, after several rejections), it will be rendered as "Fig.", "Figure", "Illustration" or whatever else, without rewriting the text.

Comment: well as you wish, but as your question shows it isn't clearly a win. if you use cleverref or similar it has the advantage of making the entire phrase a link, but personally I'd never use \figurename~\ref as that really has few advantages.